# iFrame 100% height causes vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, iframe

I see alot of questions about 100% height iFrames but noone seems to have the exact same problem as I do.

What I want to do is to have an iFrame that covers the entire viewport, with no scrollbars, without setting overflow: hidden on the body.

I get a 5px bottom margin to my iFrame that won't go away with css, and it causes a vertical scroolbar. The standard advice seems to be to set overflow: hidden on the body, but that's not really solving the problem, and it's not enough for me.

Here's a super simple [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/b64Ug/6/). (notice the double vertical scrollbars)

This behaviour is the same in Chrome 15, IE9 and FF9 for me.

Comment: I had the same issue in 2019 and display: block fixed the issue, same as on images unwanted white space below.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's not the iframe that produces the scrollbar, it's the whitespace after it

```
    <iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <!-- Whitespace here; This is being rendered! -->
</body>
```

If you don't want to see it, use

```
* { line-height: 0; }
```

---

edit: Turns out the problem persists if you remove the whitespace, but the solution is the same. Iframes are rendered as inline elements by default (iframe = '*inline* frame'), and thus have a line-height which causes the issue.

Alternatively, you may want to try `iframe { display: block; }` or a combination of both solutions.

Comment: In Chrome, when I right-clicked the white-space and chose **Inspect Element**, the `HTML` element inside the `IFRAME` was selected under the **Elements** tab. I've added a screenshot to my answer.

Comment: @davegrove Not sure if the inspector is 100% accurate there.

Comment: Tried in the two other browsers (Firefox and IE) and inspecting highlights the same element. Give it a try, what does it highlight for you?

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer. I really thought I had tried that, but I guess I hadn't.

Comment: Another simple solution to fixing the white-space issues is setting the element in question to: `iframe { display: table; }`.

Comment: Thank you :) `display: block`was enough for me.

Comment: Amazing. display:block; solved this problem for me too.

Answer (score 3):

Update:

working example in `chrome 16.0.*`, `firefox 10.*` (apparently ie9 acts up and displays a scrollbar either way -- either a disabled one if the height is set to 99% or a active one that can't scroll if height is 100%):

place the following in a html file and open it (don't know what jsfiddle is doing different, but it doesn't work the same way)

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    /*overflow: auto;*/ /* not needed, this is the default value*/
}
</style>
<iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk" frameborder="0"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what I want. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. I want the iFrame to take up the entire viewport height (and width, but that's easy). Your solution doesn't do that. I'll go ahead and edit my question so other don't get the wrong idea as well.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize it:

- white space before  causes 4px white space at the rigth of the iframe.
- white space after  csuses 4px white space after the iframe.

This is due to the inline character of iframe as pointed out in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Not seeing a vertical scroll-bar **outside** of jsFiddle with this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

iframe {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk" frameborder="0"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Here's a snippet from under the **Elements** tabs of what gets selected when I inspect the white-space in Chrome.

[image: Developer Tools Snip]

Comment: Yeah, sorry about not being clear enough. Se my other comment and my changes to the question.

Comment: Ermm :-), I'm not sure why this doesn't fit the bill. I've tweaked my answer to set the width and include a source for the `iframe`. The `iframe` itself fills the entire view-port and there's no `overflow` styling set on the containing document.

Comment: I think the `5px` gap you're seeing belongs to the document contained in the `iframe`. I can confirm this, if you right-click the gap in Chrome and choose **Inspect Element** you can see for yourself.

Comment: Ok, what browser are you using? Because without setting the height on the body to 100% you should not be able to fill the viewport with that iFrame. In fact, when I try your code in three different browsers I get the expected result of an iFrame that is 100% width and 150px in height at the top of the document.

Comment: Nope, the gap is there even if I don't set a source for the iFrame. Did you see the example? Are you experienceing the same thing?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in jsFiddle. If I create that file locally and browse that, the `iframe` fills the view-port. I've tried: Chrome (v16), Firefox (v3.6) and IE (v9).

Comment: Wow, that's wierd. I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think I can accept your answer since it's not working in jsFiddle or locally on my mashine. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder if it's worth someone else trying what I've posted to see if there's another _funky_ issue at play.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the scroll bar try this:

CSS:

```
html, body  { height:100%; margin:0;}
.bdr    { border: thick solid grey }
.h100   { height:100%;}
.w100   { Width: 100% }
.bbox   { box-sizing: border-box;
          -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        }
.vat    { font-size: 0; vertical-align:top}
```

HTML:

```
    <body class="bbox"><!-- no WS here--><iframe    
          class="bdr h100 w100 vat bbox" name="iframe1"
          src="http://www.bbc.co.uk"> </iframe><!--no WS here either--></body>
```

The .bbox style prevents sub divs from growing. .Vat is necessary for IE and Firefox.
An alternative for .vat is: display:block. Or
display:inline-block + vertical-alignment:top
.brd is for demonstration purposes.