# Remove vertical scroll bar from IFrame that gets rendered in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, webforms

The title might be a little misleading as this may be a two-part question here, I'm sorry. But I'm trying to display an iFrame (which displays an agreement pdf) and I want to detect that the user has scrolled through the document to accept the terms before continuing. I initially tried detecting that a user scrolled through the iFrame, but I couldn't hook up a scroll event to the embedded iFrame. So that's part one, if anyone has any suggestions or a link to similar answered questions about scrolling through an embedded pdf. I couldn't find a solution. Alternatively, as you'll see in the code below, I tried wrapping the iframe in an outer div and using that to detect that we've reached the bottom. Unfortunately IE shows me two vertical scroll bars.

I've searched stack for hours looking for a solution to this problem, but haven't been able to apply anything to help remove a vertical scroll bar that gets rendered in IE. Firefox and Chrome are okay. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129182/iframe-100-height-causes-vertical-scrollbar) link would work if my iframe does not contain a pdf (something with how the document gets rendered in IE).

Please let me know if I should remove any of the code if this is too convoluted, I felt these were all necessary aspects as my end goal is **to produce an iframe containing a pdf, which a user must scroll to the bottom in order to sign and submit a form.**

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
       #ifAgreement {
           height: 3390%;
       }
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="div_iframe"><asp:HtmlIframe id="ifAgreement" runat="server" scrolling="no" width="97%" height="650px">
        </asp:HtmlIframe></div>

     <asp:panel id="pnlSign" runat="server">
     <p align="center">
  Please read and scroll through the document to accept the terms of the agreement before signing and continuing.
</p>
    <div class="sigPad">
        <ul class="sigNav">
            <li class="drawIt"><a href="#draw-it" class="current">Click To Sign</a></li>
            <li class="clearButton"><a href="#clear">Clear</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="sig sigWrapper">
            <canvas class="pad" width="300" height="75" style="border: black 1px solid;"></canvas>
            <input type="hidden" name="output" class="output">
        </div>
        <br />
        <button id="btnAgreeSubmit" type="submit" style="border: thin solid #000000; width: 300px; font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; color: #000000;">
            I accept the terms of this agreement.</button>
    </div>
</asp:panel>  

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").attr("disabled", true);
        $('button').css('cursor', 'not-allowed');
        $('button').attr('title', 'You must read and scroll through the document before signing and submitting.');

        $('#div_iframe').scroll(function () {
            if ($('#ifAgreement').height() - $('#div_iframe').scrollTop() - $('#div_iframe').height() <= 100) {
                $("button").attr("disabled", false);
                $('button').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $('button').attr('title', '');
            }
        });

        var options =
    {
        bgColour: "#ffffff",
        penColour: "#000000",
        penWidth: 2,
        penCap: "solid",
        lineColour: "#cccccc",
        lineWidth: 1,
        lineMargin: 0,
        lineTop: 100
    }
        $('.sigPad').signaturePad(options);
    });
</script>


</body>

css
#div_iframe {
border-style: inset;
border-color: grey;
overflow: scroll;
height: 650px;
width: 97%;
}

#ifAgreement {
width: 100%;
height: 4000%; 
}
```

Comment: Adding **overflow: hidden on #ifAgreement** doesn't seem to do anything for my case in IE. As I see so many suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898403/iframe-always-showing-scroll-bars-in-ie7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to post my "resolution" as an answer because sometimes things get lost in comments. Make note this is a hack that I made work for my situation that may help someone along the way. While it does sort of solve my problem, I'll leave this unresolved; I'd really be open if someone else finds a better option.

```
#div_iframe {
border-style: inset;
border-color: grey;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden; /*hide the horizontal scroll bar*/
height: 650px;
width: 97%;
}

#ifAgreement {
 width: calc(100% + 15px) /*101% worked in my situation. Force the iFrame's scrollbar behind the containing div*/
 height: 3900%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use overflow: hidden for the iFrame and it will hide the IE scrollbar. The scrollbar in the PDF is part of its rendering, but I assume, from the way you worded things, that is not an issue. I think you may also need to dink with height and width of the object in the iFrame, but that is just a thought off the top of my head.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the suggestion. A "hack", I tried was to set the width of my iFrame to 101% and set overflow-x on the outer div to hidden. Which gets rid of the scroll bars, but I didn't feel like this was ideal. Maybe that's my problem in the first place. Trying to make an "ideal" solution to an unusual problem.

Comment: Many times, you just need to step back. BTW, I find my brain generally opens up right after I hit send on a question. ;-)